# How do I compile tree-sitter parsers?

Tags: gcc, neovim, tsx, treesitter

I'm trying to compile the [typescript, tsx](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-typescript), and python parsers for use with neovim, but when I run `gcc -o parser.so -shared src/parser.c -Os -I./src` as instructed by the [tree-sitter tracking issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11724) I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_tree_sitter_tsx_external_scanner_create", referenced from:
      _tree_sitter_tsx.language in parser-eb4e9b.o
  "_tree_sitter_tsx_external_scanner_deserialize", referenced from:
      _tree_sitter_tsx.language in parser-eb4e9b.o
  "_tree_sitter_tsx_external_scanner_destroy", referenced from:
      _tree_sitter_tsx.language in parser-eb4e9b.o
  "_tree_sitter_tsx_external_scanner_scan", referenced from:
      _tree_sitter_tsx.language in parser-eb4e9b.o
  "_tree_sitter_tsx_external_scanner_serialize", referenced from:
      _tree_sitter_tsx.language in parser-eb4e9b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've run the npm build steps, and tried the make file in build, but I'm not able to get the final `.so` files.

Comment: this is strange, I just get the GIT project, then go under *tsx* and I do not have problem doing `gcc -o parser.so -shared src/parser.c  -Os -I./src` (the missing definitions are in *scanner.c*)

Comment: sorry to say but are you sure that command produces the error ? Is it not later when you link with *parser.so* ?

Comment: @bruno I'm sure that's the error I get when I run the above. I'm not splitting the compile steps, since I'm specifying the .so file, so there shouldn't be another step, no?

Comment: For me you have the error when you try to make an executable linking with at least *parser.so* but without *scanner.so* (supposing this is the name for that lib) or *scanner.o* (if no lib usage for it)

Comment: @bruno I needed to include src/scanner.c in the call, i.e. `gcc -o parser.so -shared src/parser.c src/scanner.c -Os -I./src`. Gotta read the fine print. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Some grammars have [external scanners](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/creating-parsers#external-scanners) - hand written C/C++ source files that are by convention called `scanner.c` or `scanner.cc`, which need to be compiled along with `parser.c`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for in the Internet for at least some hours .... not easy to find knowing only the error message about a missing method while running the shared library from own code.

Answer (score 2):

the error `undefined symbol: tree_sitter_parsername_external_scanner_create` also appears, when there is a mismatch between parser name and function names

```js
  // grammar.js
  name: 'parsername',
```

```cc
// scanner.cc
void *tree_sitter_oldparsername_external_scanner_create() {
  return new Scanner();
}
```

quickfix: replace name in scanner source

```sh
sed -i -E 's|(tree_sitter)_oldparsername_|\1_parsername_|g' src/scanner.*
```

Answer (score 0):

nvim-treesitter is using [this](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/blob/65ef62092ef997d2ecf68ede01a0afbda17808c3/lua/nvim-treesitter/shell_command_selectors.lua#L86) which varies a bit for c++.

```
gcc -shared -o parser.so -I./src src/parser.c src/scanner.c -Os
```

If you have an older version of GCC, you might try adding `--std=c99` and `-fPIC`.  el7 comes with `gcc` 4.8.5 and this worked for me for several parsers.

```
gcc --std=c99 -shared -o parser.so -I./src src/parser.c src/scanner.c -Os -fPIC
```

Off topic, but related: If you want to use nvim-treesitter with an older compiler, see [Modifies to work with gcc 4.8 for el7 #5847](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/pull/5847)